# Which Android Camera API should a new project use?

Tags: android, camera

I am developing a new app, and I want to support all the way back to Jelly Bean/Ice Cream Sandwich. I need to use the video camera in my app - just to shoot some 15 second footage and no processing.

Do I have to write two camera Activities, one with the camera api and the other with the camera2 api, and somehow pick one based on the api level of the device?

Or, should I just use the camera api?

Which camera api would you use if you were developing a new camera based app today?

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to decide whether you really want to build a customized camera app, or you can use an existing camera app. From your question, I feel that yours is the latter case, and you can simply use an intent to invoke an existing Android camera application.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents

If you really want to build your own customized camera app, I suggest that you refer this link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

And read the following sections:

Application forward compatibility
Application backward compatibility
Selecting a platform version and API Level

Comment: Both answers to my questions are great....not sure how to give both of you a green check mark. I am pretty sure I need a custom camera app. I need to (a) add a cross-hair sight so the user can follow an object as it travels through the air; (b) measure the angle of the camera as the camera follows the object in the air; (c) have buttons to start and stop a timer to know how long the object flew through the air. The actual video recording is just a nice to have addition to the above information.

Comment: All these tasks can be covered with an app that runs in background but draws on top and listens to orientation sensor

Answer (score 3):

For the near future, the deprecated Camera API will not disappear, even on the cutting-edge new devices. I would recommend to switch to Camera2 if one of the following causes applies:

- your app makes good use of some of the new features, e.g. capture-while-recording.
- your app has other reasons not to be backwards-compatible under API v.21 (Lollipop), e.g. it only runs on ARM64.
- you want to practice or demonstrate your skills with the new API.

**PS** and I support the first suggestion from [SAg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2790269/sag): use the Camera Intent if you only need what such intent can provide. A short unprocessed video clip is a good example.

Comment: Thanks for your real-world answer! It makes me feel better that I can start with the deprecated camera api (lots more documentation on how to use it), and then work in the new api as more example code is created by the brave early adopters!

Comment: Hi Alex, I have a feeling that you might be able to help me out with my question. Please have a look (I work mostly on platforms, and only have basic knowledge about frameworks)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255954/android-camera-framework-for-api2

Comment: @SumitAgrawal: I would be glad to read an educated answer, too. I am not an expert of AIDL.

Comment: I see. Thanks anyways.