# Another Option to replace android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback which is deprecated

Tags: android, android-camera

I need to retrieve captured picture with android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback but it is deprecated, have you any suggestions to replace it thanks !

Comment: Note that the deprecated API is supported on all today's consumer devices, while `camera2` is available only on Lollypop and higher platforms, and even for these devices there are quite a few known glitches. See also [my detailed answer to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249693/which-android-camera-api-should-a-new-project-use/33258618#33258618)

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation you need to use [android.hardware.camera2](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)

To handle events related to JPEG capture use **CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback**

A full sample is [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/241c6fac8113ddb5dffb4f349b5bb9f1bea93501/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java)

Comment: While you are correct that `android.hardware.Camera` was deprecated and replaced by the `android.hardware.camera2` API, `CameraDevice.StateCallback` is not an equivalent of `Camera.PictureCallback`.

Comment: you are right @CommonsWare StateCallback receive updates about the state of a camera device and PictureCallback normally is used after a user take a picture

Comment: Then what is the solution of it..??
I also not found **Camera.width**